# X-й век, 1940й год.

Tags: стилистика

Почему

```
XX-й век - это 19xx+, 
Шестой час - это 5:xx+ или 17:xx+,
а восемьдесят третий год - это xx83, а не xx82+?!
```

P.S. при всем при том что 
"ей пошел 17 год" = ей **16 лет** и нескольлко месяцев

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак.
Часы. С ними все ясно, т.к. отсчет идет с 0:00. Получается первый час - это час с 0:00 до 1:00. Дальше по аналогии.
Века. Уже запутаннее. Мы считаем века с первого. Нулевого века нет. И уже числительное мы записываем цифрами. Т.е. года с 1-го года р.х. - первый век. Причем возикает прикол, что года, оканчивающиеся на 00, принадлежат к предыдущему веку. Например, 2000-й год - это ХХ век, а не ХХI.

Хочу сказать, что в некоторых языках есть разница между числительными. Привожу пример. Венгерский: [első](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/els%C5%91)(первый по счету) и [egyes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egyes) (первый по номеру), помимо собственно [egy](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/egy) (число один и кол-во предметов один).

Русский язык. Третий троллейбус.
Это какой? Либо третий по счету, либо троллейбус под номером три. Увы, в русском языке есть такая неоднозначность. В частности, неприятной она становится при работе с компьютерами, т.к. в них принята нумерация с 0. Например, первый байт. Это какой байт? Под номером 0 или под номером 1?

**Итого. Получается, что все зависит от того, что мы принимаем в качестве начала отсчета какой-либо величины: собственно 0 или 1.**

Comment: Про века и компьютеры - это все хорошо, хотя с компьтерами можно и поспорить. Венгерский - на вашей совести, как и то, какое это отношение имеет к вопросы. Троллейбусов мой бендый "мосх" не выдержал. Третий троллебус - он всегда и третий, и номер три, только в разных системах. 
Если есть хоть малейшая путаница, то говорят "третий маршрут" или "марсшрут номер три".

Но я вот одного не понял. На какой вопрос вы отвечаете?  
Вот хоть танец с бубнами устраивай, а xx83 г. - это именно xx82 + что-то. Или вы тоже думаете как автор? Не похоже, судя по пониманию момента начала века...

Comment: Но я вот одного не понял. На какой вопрос вы отвечаете?  
Вот хоть танец с бубнами устраивай, а xx83 г. - это именно xx82 + что-то. Или вы тоже думаете как автор? Не похоже, судя по пониманию момента начала века...

ЗЫ я правда не понимаю, о чем речь. Всегда считал, что в этом вопросе нет никих тонкостей. Кроме разве элементарного понимания того, что Христианская эра начинается в 1-й год, не в нулевой.

ЗЗЫ А нумерация года в венгерском как-то различается от того, по номеру он или по счету?

ЗЗЗЫ Гугл:   
első  - первый  
egyes  - один  
ну это-то то не удивительно...

Comment: ЗЗЫ. Да.
ЗЗЗЫ. Существует еще "egy", т.е. само числительное "один". И это принципиально.

Comment: Касательно летоисчисления. [Нет в григорианском исчислении 0-го года.][1]. Хоть об стенку расшибитесь.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA

Comment: И вообще - дайте поныть, а? :-)

Comment: >Нет в григорианском исчислении 0-го года.  
Это я знаю. В юлианском тоже. Его нет в Хиждре, еврейском календаре, китайском и каледаре майя.   
И что??? Я где-то говорил, что он есть?  
    
>Нет. Извините, но если номер 3, то это уже точно не третий по счету
Не извиняю.))) Пока не скажете, какой он тогда. Второй? Четвертый?  
Третий - это если до него было два. Номер три - если до него были (или могли быть) номер один и номер два.

Comment: > ЗЗЗЫ. Существует еще "egy", т.е. само числительное "один". И это принципиально.  
Я таки попробую повторить аопрос. Нумерация года в венгерском как-то различается от того, по номеру он или по счету?
Какой сейчас год по венгерскому номеру и по венгерскому счету?

Comment: > Не извиняю.))) Пока не скажете, какой он тогда. Второй? Четвертый?

Попробуйте объяснить англичанину, что ему нужно сесть в третий автобус, едущий по третьему маршруту. Проблема ведь не только в автобусах. Проблема вообще в отсутствии в русском языке различия между порядковыми обозначениями и номерами. Или точнее возможности их различия на практике. Например, представьте себе улицу. На ней идет нумерация домов. Дом №1, дом №3, дом №5. Это по нечетной стороне. Но вот, например, дома №7 нет и идет сразу №9. При этом по порядку они будут первый (№1), второй (№3), третий (№5) и четвертый (№9).

Comment: Тоже самое с номерами квартир или комнат в многоквартирных домах, гостиницах и общежитиях. Не обязательно на этаже номер комнаты будет соответствовать ее расположению относительно входа.

> Нумерация года в венгерском как-то различается от того, по номеру он или по счету?

Это непринципиально. См. выше. Там вообще по времени отдельная история. Но нумерация там вполне стандартная.

Answer (score 3):

Как говорится, в каком году начался 21-й век - второй ящик водки начинается с 21-й бутылки...

Answer (score 1):

2012 год  это  порядковое  обозначение текущего отрезка  времени. На  всём  протяжении  этого  отрезка. Когда  человеку  16  лет,  значит,  что  он  уже  прожил  16,  и  находится  в  следующим  по  порядку  17-м.  Относительно  путаницы  между  поряковыми  обозначениями  и  другими  цифровыми,  то  она  появяется  в  речевой  практике,  в  какой-нибудь  определённой  среде,  например:  "Вихрь" двадцатый  вместо  "Вихрь" двадцатисильный. Почему-то  у  лодочников  было  так  принято.

Answer (score 0):

Не понял вопроса. 
1983-й год - это именно **1982 полных года плюс несколько месяцев** - тех, что прошли с начала этого года.

ЗЫ Если, пренебрегая несколькими днями декабря или января, взять за Рождество 1 января 1 года н.э., то Христу сейчас 2011 лет, 9 месяцев, 21 день, 17 часов и 36 минут. Полная аналогия с вашей юной знакомой.

~~~~
Сколько меня не убезжадал в обратном (хотя в обратном ли?) уважаемый gecube, я остался при своем мнении. Никаких причин считать, что "xx83-й год" это "xx83 + месяцы" нет и не было.
1983-й - **это именно 1983-й, порядковое числительное, означающее, что до этого года прошло 1982. Хоть по счету, хоть по номеру**. Хоть по-венгерски, хоть по-китайски.
Тоже самое будет, если назвать этот год "годом номер 1983". Тоже самое с часами, неделями, веками и возрастом подружек... Хотя вот с возрастом могут быть коммуникативные тонкости, определямые культурой. На Востке, например, люди становятся старше на год в день Нового года по востояному календарю. А монголы считали возраст мальчиков от дня первой стрижки...
Но это все разговоры совершенно другого порядка. Никаких сложностей с употреблением именно порядковых числительных я не вижу.

Других содержательных предметов для обсуждения ни в вопросе, ни в пространном ответе gecube не вижу.

gecube:

> А Вы не пишите хх82+месяцы... т.к. сбивает с толку.

Простие, но:  
~1. меня не сбивает, а наоборот помогает разобраться во всей этой элементарщине раздутой до вселенской проблемы. Кого сбивает - выходи строиться, считать буду, кто объяснит, что именно его сбюивает.  
~2. эту запись использовал автор вопроса как единственное пояснения к своим непоняткам.   
~3. вы все-таки скажите, прав автор вопрос или нет. "Сбивает" - это уже другой вопрос.

> Это хх.хх.хх82 подразумевается?

Нет. О подобном даже речи не шло. хх.хх.хх82 - это именно 82-й год. А спрашивали про 83-й. И проводили аналогии с часами и прочим.

> Или хх82 с момента Чэ?

С нуля. С 0:00 01.01.01, принимаемое за условное начало Христианской эры.

> Так что Вы сами себя запутываете.

Простите, но у вас нет ни малешейшего повода так утверждать. Разве я сказал что-то, что вы реально опровергли? Пока что меня путаете вы своими венгерскими троллейбусами.

> Лично я нигде не возражал, что 1983-й год - это год по записи 1983 + месяцы,

Понятно, хотя и некорректно. ))) Отсюда и все ваши автобусы. Вы вслед за автором смешиваете порядковые числительные (в коих нет ничего сложного, уверяю вас) и систему записи календарной даты (в которой тоже больших сложностей нет).

> но по факту с даты 1 января 1 прошло 1982 полных лет.

Простите, но о чем тогда столько разговоров? Достаточно было это сказать вопрошающему, обвинившему меня чуть ли не в подготовке конца света.   
Во всяком случае - с этого начать. Тогда все остальное читалось бы (ну лично мной) даже с некоторым интересом. )))

> Это непринципиально. См. выше. Там вообще по времени отдельная история. Но нумерация там вполне стандартная.
> Что и требовалось доказать. Это нигде не принципиально. Ибо "третий" и "номер три" вне каких-то сумасшедших контекстов ознвчают один и тот же предмет.

ЗЗЗЗЗЗЫ. Спасибо, кризис миновал, мой мозг спасён. 
Небольшое продолжение будет через какое-то время в отдельной теме. Никоим образом затронутых вопросов не касающееся, просто вспомнилось одно незакрытое обсуждение на грамоте.

Comment: Сейчас 2012й. И "конец света" 21 декабря 2012го, а не 2013го, как вы утверждаете. Ну и так далее.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Я что-то уьверждаю про "конец света"?

Comment: >Попробуйте объяснить англичанину,  
      
Лучше бы вы попробовали объяснить это мне. 
Вы хотите чтобы он пропустил два третьих или два любых?
Take the (third) bus after missing two ones - в зависимости от смысла. Как-то так. А зачем это все? В ангийском уж точно нет никаких различий между поряковыми числительными в зависимости от объекта счета. В китайском вот их до девяноста типов, и никто никогда не путается с тем, по номеру автобус или по счету.

>Проблема вообще в отсутствии в русском языке различия между порядковыми обозначениями и номерами. 
Я вижу только одну проблему.

Comment: Может кто-то из математиков все-таки объяснит, почему xx83-й год - это не xx82+месяцы, а именно xx83 + что-то, как счтает атор вопроса, а вселед за ним, судя по разговору, и уважаемый gecube, и сколько я должен пропустить перед посадкой автобусов, если мне сказали "третий маршрут", а не "маршрут номер три".
@DocentI, может спасете мой воспаленный разум?

Comment: А Вы не пишите хх82+месяцы. Т.к. сбивает с толку. Это хх.хх.хх82 подразумевается? Или хх82 с момента Чэ? Так что Вы сами себя запутываете. Лично я нигде не возражал, что 1983-й год - это год по записи 1983 + месяцы, но по факту с даты 1 января 1 прошло 1982 полных лет.

Answer (score 0):

Для knes  
Сынок, ты меня пордряс. 
Это для тебя. Сегодня. Наисвежайшее.
Help Wanted - Требуются 
Mathematics Assistant Professor in Residence
Las Vegas,, NV
University of Nevada, Las Vegas - UNLV

---

University College,Assistant/Associate Professors/Professors,Department of Mathematics and Statistics,Abu Dhabi and Dubai,August 2015/January 2016
Zayed University

---

Mathematics Instructor
Fremont, CA
Ohlone College

---

Faculty Positions (All Levels- Assistant Professors, Associate Professors, Professor & Senior Professors)
Pilani-333031, Rajasthan
Birla Institute of Technology and Science (BITS) Pilani, Pilani- 333031, Rajasthan (INDIA)